# pyinstaller and external software setup

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I need to distribute additional software together with my exe file created with pyinstaller.

For example mysql connector works fine, but the final user should install mysql on his computer. While this could be easily achieved by telling the user to install it, I would like to avoid this, since it could lead to some issues with less experienced users. That is, I want it to be fool-proof.

Same story for Tesseract Ocr. In that case I also need to add it to PATH, but this is a secondary issue.

How to handle this external setup installation? I didn't find a way to include them in the exe generated by pyinstaller, but maybe I'm missing something.

The only idea I had is to add the installers in the same folder of my executable folder and run them somehow during the first run.. Any suggestion?